# JTextField showing up on Mac but not on Windows

Tags: java, swing, cross-platform, jtextfield, compatibility

My brother requested me to make a simple GUI application which calculates his tax in a game he is playing. So I quickly assembled this code. I literally used 5 minutes, as I just wanted it to work quickly:

```
    public class MainGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener  {

    private static final double EA_TAX = 0.05;

    private JButton btnProfit;
    private JTextField buyPrice;
    private JTextField sellPrice;
    private JTextField resultField;
    private JLabel buyLabel;
    private JLabel sellLabel;
    private static final NumberFormat NUMBER_FORMAT = NumberFormat.getInstance();
    JPanel container;

    public MainGUI(){
        this.setSize(400,400);
        container = new JPanel();
        btnProfit = new JButton("Calculate");
        buyPrice = new JFormattedTextField(getIntFormatter(NUMBER_FORMAT));
        sellPrice = new JFormattedTextField(getIntFormatter(NUMBER_FORMAT));
        resultField = new JTextField();
        buyLabel = new JLabel("The price you intend to pay");
        sellLabel = new JLabel("Price you intend to sell the player for");
        resultField.setEditable(false);
        btnProfit.addActionListener(this);
        GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(3,2);
        container.setLayout(gridLayout);
        container.add(buyLabel);
        container.add(sellLabel);
        container.add(buyPrice);
        container.add(sellPrice);
        container.add(btnProfit);
        container.add(resultField);

        container.setVisible(true);
        this.add(container);

        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

    private NumberFormatter getIntFormatter(NumberFormat NUMBER_FORMAT)    {
        NumberFormatter formatter = new NumberFormatter(NUMBER_FORMAT);
        formatter.setValueClass(Integer.class);
        formatter.setMinimum(0);
        formatter.setMaximum(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        //formatter.setAllowsInvalid(false);
        formatter.setCommitsOnValidEdit(true);


        return formatter;
        }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == this.btnProfit){
            this.resultField.setText("" +determineProfitAfterTax(Integer.parseInt(buyPrice.getText().replace(",", "")), Integer.parseInt(sellPrice.getText().replace(",", ""))));
        }
    }

    private int determineProfitAfterTax(int buyPrice, int sellPrice){
        return (int) (sellPrice * (1.00 - EA_TAX)) - buyPrice;
    }
}
```

in the Java class MainApplication.java i instantiate the `JFrame`:

```
public class MainApplication {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        new MainGUI();
    }
}
```

All of the text fields show up except the `resultField` `JTextField`, which is the one that holds the result. Any particular reason this works on Mac and not on windows? All input is appreciated.

Comment: Construct and manipulate Swing GUI objects _only_ on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: @trashgod I saw the link but I did not quite understand. Could you give me an example?

Comment: Your `main()` should call `EventQueue.invokeLater()`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a230513%20EventQueue.invokeLater).

Comment: @trashgod Thank-you for the example trashgod :)

Comment: If this turns out to be the essential problem, you can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by constructing the GUI Swing GUI options on the event dispatch thread (strongly suggested by the user @trashgod. To clarify, instead of doing this:

```
public class MainApplication {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        new MainGUI();
    }
}
```

do this:

```
public class MainApplication {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MainGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Please always try and use the second approach, even though it may seem that your program works when using the first approach. Using the first approach produces very weird side effects.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed some mistakes. Now it work in the Windows.`

```
  import javax.swing.*;

  import javax.swing.text.NumberFormatter;
  import java.awt.*;
  import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
  import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
  import java.text.NumberFormat;

  public class MainGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

private static final double EA_TAX = 0.05;

private JButton btnProfit;
private JTextField buyPrice;
private JTextField sellPrice;
private JTextField resultField;
private JLabel buyLabel;
private JLabel sellLabel;
private static final NumberFormat NUMBER_FORMAT =     NumberFormat.getInstance();
JPanel container;

public MainGUI(){
    this.setSize(400,400);
    container = new JPanel();
    btnProfit = new JButton("Calculate");
    buyPrice = new JFormattedTextField(getIntFormatter(NUMBER_FORMAT));
    sellPrice = new JFormattedTextField(getIntFormatter(NUMBER_FORMAT));
    resultField = new JTextField();
    buyLabel = new JLabel("The price you intend to pay");
    sellLabel = new JLabel("Price you intend to sell the player for");
    resultField.setEditable(false);
    btnProfit.addActionListener(this);
    GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(3,2);
    container.setLayout(gridLayout);
    container.add(buyLabel);
    container.add(sellLabel);
    container.add(buyPrice);
    container.add(sellPrice);
    container.add(btnProfit);
    container.add(resultField);

    container.setVisible(true);
    this.add(container);

    this.pack();
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}

private NumberFormatter getIntFormatter(NumberFormat NUMBER_FORMAT)    {
    NumberFormatter formatter = new NumberFormatter(NUMBER_FORMAT);
    formatter.setValueClass(Integer.class);
    formatter.setMinimum(0);
    formatter.setMaximum(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    //formatter.setAllowsInvalid(false);
    formatter.setCommitsOnValidEdit(true);


    return formatter;
}



public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == this.btnProfit){
        this.resultField.setText("" +determineProfitAfterTax(Integer.parseInt(buyPrice.getText().replace(",", "")), Integer.parseInt(sellPrice.getText().replace(",", ""))));
    }
}

private int determineProfitAfterTax(int buyPrice, int sellPrice){
    return (int) (sellPrice * (1.00 - EA_TAX)) - buyPrice;
}
}`
```

Comment: You did absolutely no changes. What are you talking about? You only added those import changes. Also, when you say that you "fixed" something, specify what you have fixed. You just copy and pasted mine into your IDE, imported the libraries and pasted it back here. Post is confusing and should not have been made in the first place.

Comment: @tomSurge: This is an example of how an incorrectly synchronized program, i.e. without `EventQueue.invokeLater()`, can _appear_ to run correctly on one platform and fail on another.